# Getting undefined here. Any reason why?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

So I am currently making a chrome extension that allows you to set shortcuts to websites and go to them directly. But for some reason I am currently, here, getting undefined at the `command1`

Here is the code:

```js
let current_url = document.getElementsByClassName("current_url");
let bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
let url = ""
let storage = chrome.storage.sync
console.log(chrome)
console.log(bg)
console.log(bg.command1)
function adder(){
    for(elt of current_url) {
       switch(elt.innerHTML) {
           case "command1":
               chrome.storage.sync.get("key1", function(msg){url = msg.key1.toString(); console.log(msg.key1)});
               break;
           case "command2":
                 url = bg.command2;
                break;
           case "command3":
                url = bg.command3;
               break;
            case "command4":
                url = bg.command4;
                break;
       }
       elt.innerHTML = `${elt.innerHTML}       ${url}`;
       console.log(elt)
    }
}
adder()
```

```css
.change-c{
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: grey;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src= "app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class= "change-c">
        <p class= "current_url">command1</p><li><input type="text" class="enter"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="change-c">
        <p class= "current_url">command2</p><li><input type="text" class="enter"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="change-c">
        <p class= "current_url">command3</p><li><input type="text" class="enter"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class= "change-c">
        <p class= "current_url">command4</p><li><input type="text" class="enter"></li>
    </ul>
    
</body>
</html>
```

So any ideas why this is happening? Like at `console.log("msg.key1")` it does say "https://www.youtube.com"  but the variable "url" is undefined even though they are the same. Please help if u can

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Try `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` maybe there are hidden characters there..

Comment: the problem is that I am getting the var "url" undefined, but innerhtml is working everywhere else

Comment: When `command1`, you don't set the `url` variable, only in the other `case`s.

Comment: @MoshFeu OP sets the `url` in the callback of `chrome.storage.sync.get`. (Hence it is a duplicate of the link I posted in my first comment.)

Comment: You're right @Ivar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chrome.storage.sync.get` is an asynchronous operation and when the value is retrieved it will invoke the function in the second parameter.

In your code you are reading the value of the variable right after calling this asynchronous function, so the value of the variable is still not set yet until the callback function is invoked.

To resolve this issue, either

1. set the innerHTML in the callback function or

OR

2. promisify the function, convert `adder` to async function and use await for the promise